# Eigenbasis and Linear Combination for Mixing Times

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mixing

I am working on something for Markov Chain mixing times and I am stuck on a piece of linear algebra.

Assume an $n \times n$ matrix M has all simple eigenvalues.  Therefore, there is a basis of eigenvectors.  Let $v_1$ be an eigenvector of norm 1.  Is it always possible to find eigenvectors $v_2 \dots v_n$ all with norm 1 such that $v_1 \dots v_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and have the property that:

$e_i = v_1 + \sum_{k=2}^n a_kv_k$.

(the coefficient in front of $v_1$ is 1)

The paper I am reading assumes this is true but I am not certain why it must be true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be more to this, because the claim as stated doesn’t hold. It’s tantamount to saying that, having chosen a unit eigenvector $v_1$, there is some eigenbasis (having unit vectors for the rest of it irrelevant) for which $e_i-v_1\in\operatorname{span}\{v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ for *every* standard basis vector $e_i$. In other words, the first coordinate of *every* standard basis vector relative to this basis is $1$.

As a simple counterexample, let $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb r^2$ with one eigenspace spanned by $(1,1)^T$ and the other by $(0,1)^T$. Setting $v_1$ to $\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)^T$, $e_i-v_1\ne (0,k)^T$ for any $k$.

Now, if the matrix is stochastic, then there might be a version of this claim that does work, although I still doubt that you can choose *any* unit eigenvector for $v_1$. The fact that $1$ is always an eigenvalue of a stochastic matrix might play into it.

Comment: It is a stochastic matrix; I should have mentioned that